# $\sigma$ - algebra generated by stopping times F and T

Tags: measure-theory

I found this in my stochastic processes script:

Suppose $S,T$ are $({F}_{n})$-stopping times.

S $\leq $ T a.s $\Rightarrow$ $F_{S} \subseteq F_{T}$.

My problem now is that we only assume the inequality S $\leq $ T almost sure. But for me, this isn't enough to conclude  $F_{S} \subseteq F_{T}$. So I would remove the a.s, so that the inequality must be true $\forall \omega$.

Is this a mistake in my script or am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome. You should give a lot more context than this.

Comment: What you are saying is very true. Almost sure equality is not enough.